# Git: repo for multiple users on a server

Tags: git, unix, file-permissions, shared

I created a Git repo on a server and want it to be used by several people, i.e. users which belong to the same Unix group. It also has a working copy because it may be useful for us to have a common working copy.

Thus I set the owning group of that Git repo directory to that Unix group.

The problem is, every time someone is pushing to that repository, the new files/directories have the owner set to the username of that user and his group but not our common group. Also, all those new files/directories become `rwxr-xr-x`.

I tried `git config core.sharedRepository group` but that doesn't really work. It now makes files/directories as `rwxrwsr-x` but is has still the wrong group set.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.

The first important thing (which I did already) was:

```
git config core.sharedRepository group
```

The second one was this:

```
chmod g+s -R .
```

Comment: if you add more repos, you'll have to repeat this.

Comment: `git init --shared=group` does this for you, including on an existing repo.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend you use [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) for any rights management within an organization and git. This has made management of the repos so much easier.